# How to glob files into folders depending on their prefix

Tags: powershell, directory, glob, prefix, windows-11

I have 4000 fish picture files, named as follows:

```
acanthistius_cinctus_1
acanthistius_cinctus_2
acanthopagrus_latus_1
acanthopagrus_latus_2
...
```

There are 468 species.

In order to train a computer vision model, I need to group these files to have a folder for each species with related picture inside.

Like this :

```
acanthistius_cinctus/ 
                     acanthistius_cinctus_1
                     acanthistius_cinctus_2
```

I need a PowerShell script because I'm a bit lost with other types of scripts.

Comment: Share your code attempt at solving the problem and we might be able to help you

Comment: take a look at the various properties you get for each object when you use `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Item` on a file. [*grin*]

Comment: While there is no solution attempt, the question is still well defined (enough) and presents a problem that I believe to be of general interest. Therefore I think it should be reopened. The following may work, but should obviously be presented in the form of an answer: `Get-ChildItem -File | 
  Group-Object { ($_.Name -split '_')[0,1] -join '_' } |
    ForEach-Object {      
      $_.Group | Move-Item -WhatIf -Destination (NewItem -Force -Type Directory $_.Name).FullName
    }` Note: operates on the current dir; `-WhatIf` previews the operation.

Comment: There are many utilities like RenameMaster that do this, why must you use a PowerShell script?